# react.js useState doesn't update the

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a series of 4 dropdowns with filtering of the available items of the 2nd based on the selection of the 1st, and so on down to the 4th. The 1st, 2nd and 3rd work as expected, but the 4th never has any items in it. All of the typeahead dropdowns use the same component, so there is no difference in the code used between them.

Here is the component that is giving me grief, the relevant typeahead is the last that uses availableSpots for its items.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { Table } from "react-bootstrap";
import { UseFetchCountries, UseFetchStates, UseFetchWaters, UseFetchSpots } from "./hooks/SearchBarHooks";
import TypeAheadDropDown from "./Typeaheads/TypeAheadDropDown";

const SearchBar = () => {
    const dbCountries = UseFetchCountries("http://localhost:3033/country");
    const dbStates = UseFetchStates("http://localhost:3033/state");
    const dbWaters = UseFetchWaters("http://localhost:3033/water");
    const dbSpots = UseFetchSpots("http://localhost:3033/spot");

    const [availableStates, setAvailableStates] = useState(dbStates);
    const [availableWaters, setAvailableWaters] = useState(dbWaters);
    const [availableSpots, setAvailableSpots] = useState(dbSpots);

    const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState({});
    const [selectedState, setSelectedState] = useState({});
    const [selectedWater, setSelectedWater] = useState({});
    const [selectedSpot, setSelectedSpot] = useState({});

    const selectCountryHandler = (country) => {
        setSelectedCountry(country);
        setAvailableStates(dbStates.filter((state) => state.country_id == country.id));
        console.log("===> selectCountryHandler > availableSpots: " + JSON.stringify(availableSpots));
    };

    const selectStateHandler = (state) => {
        setSelectedState(state);
        setAvailableWaters(dbWaters.filter((water) => state.id == water.state_id));
        console.log("===> selectStateHandler > availableSpots: " + JSON.stringify(availableSpots));
    };

    const selectWaterHandler = (water) => {
        setSelectedWater(water);
        console.log("===> water: " + JSON.stringify(water));
        console.log("===> dbSpots: " + JSON.stringify(dbSpots));
        setAvailableSpots(dbSpots.filter((spot) => spot.water_id == water.id));
        console.log("===> Filtered Spots: " + JSON.stringify(dbSpots.filter((spot) => spot.water_id == water.id)));
        console.log("===> selectStateHandler > availableSpots: " + JSON.stringify(availableSpots));
    };

    const selectSpotHandler = (spot) => {
        setSelectedSpot(spot);
    };

    const isButtonEnabled = () => {
        if (selectedCountry.id && selectedState.id && selectedWater.id && selectedSpot.id) {
            return "{{false}}";
        }

        return "{{disabled}}";
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        setAvailableSpots(dbSpots.filter((spot) => spot.water_id == selectedWater.id));
    }, [dbSpots, selectedWater]);

    return (
        <div className="container-fluid h-100">
            <div className="row bordered-component">
                <h4>Select your filters</h4>
                <Table className="table search-bar-filter">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td className="dd-label-cell">
                                <h6>Country: </h6>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <TypeAheadDropDown items={dbCountries} countrySelected={selectCountryHandler} />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td className="dd-label-cell">
                                <h6>State/Region: </h6>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <TypeAheadDropDown items={availableStates} parent={selectedCountry} stateSelected={selectStateHandler} />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td className="dd-label-cell">
                                <h6>Water: </h6>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <TypeAheadDropDown items={availableWaters} parent={selectedState} waterSelected={selectWaterHandler} />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td className="dd-label-cell">
                                <h6>Spot: </h6>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <TypeAheadDropDown items={availableSpots} parent={selectedWater} spotSelected={selectSpotHandler} />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>
                                <Button className="float-right" variant="success" disabled={isButtonEnabled()}>
                                    Get Fishing Reports
                                </Button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default SearchBar;
```

The console logs show that the data is retrieved from the REST endpoint in the useFetch* functions and dbSpots is properly set. But availableSpots is never set.

Comment: Hmmm, you call `setAvailableSpots` both in an effect and in the `selectWaterHandler ` - is this intended? Might be something going on conflicting there?

Comment: Your code would be greatly simplified by removing the `useState` calls for the API data and just run `.filter` calls based on what's in the selected states

Comment: Nikki9696, I commented out the call to setAvailableSpots in the selecteWaterHandler with no change in behavior. Matthew Herbst, are you saying that I shouldn't use useState for the selected* and available* variables? The db* variables aren't managed via state variables already. the UseFetch* functions just do asynchronous fetches to the REST API to set their initial values.